# Add loading view during process of the next view in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to add a loading page during the process, I tried all the solutions here in stackoverflow and different articales, but I'm really surprised that the solutions did not work for me, It's been 2 days and I still didn't find a solution.

I have two pages Home and datatable I want to add a loading page when i redirect from the home page to the datatable one. Please any help is highly appreciated.

this is my view.py :

```
def home_view(request):
    context = {}
    context ['form'] = Scraping()
    return render(request,'home.html', context)
def datatable_view(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request,'datatable.html')
```

Comment: Which process are you talking about? Where you want to add the template?

Comment: @SunderamDubey loading time of response meanwhile show loading circle effect

Comment: just the time while waiting for the datatable view to render. Yes that's what I mean

Comment: aware of ajax calls? maybe that can help. create html content of loading effect. keep it hidden by default while ajax calls are made show that component and after sucess Response make it display None again

Comment: I tried this solution multiple time I it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i told you ajax calls should work i tried and its working. here's code
in local i had to set TimeOut fuction because response is quick so cant see loading effect.

Html:

```
<style>
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>

<div class="loader" style="display: none;" id="id_loader"></div>
```

Js click event:

```
function saveProfile() {
            var postData = new FormData();
            let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
            postData.append('profile_id', $("#id_profile_id").val().trim());
            postData.append('user_id', $("#id_user_id").val().trim());
            postData.append('username', $("#id_username").val().trim());
            postData.append('password', $("#id_password").val().trim());
            postData.append('first_name', $("#id_first_name").val().trim());
            postData.append('last_name', $("#id_last_name").val().trim());
            postData.append('phone', $("#id_phone").val().trim());
            postData.append('email', $("#id_email").val().trim());
            postData.append('address', $("#id_address").val().trim());

            $("#id_loader").show()
            setTimeout(function () {
                axios({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "http://192.168.1.249:7001/profile_save/",
                    data: postData,
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", 'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}', Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, },
                }).then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data && response.data.code == 1) {
                        $("#id_loader").hide();
                        swal("Successful!", response.data.msg, "success")
                    }
                    else if (response.data.code == 0) {
                        $("#id_loader").hide();
                        swal("Oops!", response.data.msg, "error")
                    }
                })
            }, 2000);
        }
```